# 'BadRequest' when send to specify groups - Bot Framework 4

Tags: .net-core, botframework, chatbot, skype-bots

I have an issue with Skype Chatbot. I have integrated chatbot in my system, store group conversationId, serviceUrl, etc... in DB and send to these groups when needed. My system is using .NET Core 2.2 and Bot Framework 4 (version 4.7.0), the system worked well until yesterday.
I have only 2 groups that cannot receive messages from Bot, the other groups still receive messages. My service throws the exception "Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'". These groups had received messages normal from the same Bot before yesterday. This is my issue.
I try to update the Bot Framework up to the latest version (4.11.1), but the issue still not solved. I even remove this bot from these groups and re-add the bot again but still not work.
Please help me explain and resolve this case, thank you.
I have posted this issue in https://support.snatchbot.me/discuss/5fc8aeaf450c2201ac84b4b5

Comment: do you get any additional error on the Skype channel's health tab on Azure or on the Dev Console(Ctrl + Shift + I) for Skype chat? Also, have you tried to restart the bot and test ?

Comment: hi @ranusharao. The result from Azure does not provide more info. Here is the result from [Azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mLWO.png) 
All groups failed are have common format group ID like ...@p2p.thread.skype
The messages sent to the other groups still successful (with the same code).
My system worked smoothly for more than a year. The issue just occur about a week ago. I don't know if there are some changes on Azure bot. Here is the same 
[issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65175895/skype-bot-cannot-send-messages-to-some-group-from-special-day-although-it-works)

Comment: that's weird. What other aspects might be common in the groups which are failing? Also, if you don't mind, can you share your bot handle or App ID(my email is on my SO profile) so that I can try checking the logs on our end to get more info? Do you still get the issue even after restarting the bot?

Comment: hi @ranusharao. I have shared more information in your email (my email is on my SO profile too). Thanks