# Skype bot cannot send messages to some group from special day although it works fine before

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service, skype-bots

We have implement a Skype bot using Bot Builder 4. And this bot run smoothly around 2 years. But from recent days some specify groups cannot receive proactive message from the bot. We have traced both production & development environment to narrow down issue as below:

1. Those group cannot receive message all have format as: ...@p2p.thread.skype. When we create new group and add this bot into group (new group have format: ...@thread.skype). The message send successfully to new group.
2. We have get source code Bot Builder 4 from Github and add to my project to debug and see below:

- This is group send fail:
  [fail group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2DcK.png)
- This is group send sucessfull:
  [sucess group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hc6k0.png)

3. We got meaningless warning from my azure portal:
   [azure warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mLWO.png)

I don't know if Skype bot has just changed any rules or restrictions about their service?

I am very pleased and appreciate any sharing from everyone.

Comment: Skype recently deployed new certificates on some of their servers which may be the root cause of your issue. The recommended step is to restart your bot to pick up the new certs. Please try this and best of luck!

Comment: Thank you for the help @StevenKanberg but I can not find any method to restart bot? Could you give me the detail for it? I must restart API endpoint (from my code) or restart from azure or restart from Skype app?

Comment: I have tried deleting Skype channel from Azure portal but the result is the same. I've also created a new bot and add into a fail group and also not resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is a bug from Skype backend service. The MS team has just confirmed on this github:

> This is a confirmed bug on Skype backend side. The issue has been
> mitigated for the specific bot and the general fix will be rolled out
> on the first week of January.

https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Services/issues/270#issuecomment-752455967